# Nested GridView - Get ID from Parent

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio-2010

I am stuck here.

I have a `GridView` with another `GridView` (As A Template Column as a User Control) nested in it.
Both are bound to an `ObjectDataSource`. My Problem now is how I pass the ID from the Parent Row to the Child Grid in order to only show the relevant data.

Example:

```
<ParentGridView>
 <Columns>
  <ID/>
  <ChildGridView/>
 </Columns>
</ParentGridView>
```

How can i pass the ID from ParentGridView to ChildGridView ?

Thank you.

Comment: Gridview is not a valid control in Columns. You will get the error DataControlFieldCollection must have items of type 'DataControlField'. 'asp:GridView' is of type 'GridView'. You will need a TemplateField for that.

Comment: I do have a Template Field. Sorry if my question is not clear enough.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try something like this

```
var gvParent= (GridViewRow)gvChild.Parent.Parent;
```

or

`var gvParent= (GridViewRow)gvChild.Parent.Parent.Parent;`

Also have a look at this article about [Creating a Nested GridView Control](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa992038%28v=vs.80%29.aspx)